# Insert string to Dataframe in python 3.6.0

Tags: python, python-3.6

I want to find the folder path for all `.gz` files from network folder.
I have below `script` but its giving `error`:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object
```

Please help on the same

Script:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

adcPath = r'\\ADC\redshift-datasets\BLSCEWAG2016'

gzPath = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Path'], dtype=object)
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(adcPath):
for name in files:
if name.endswith('.gz'):
gzPath = gzPath.append(path) # Want to insert to dataframe gzPath to export in csv

gzPath = gzPath['Path'].unique()
exportPath = r'D:\Sunil_Work\temp8' + '\\Path.csv'
gzPath.to_csv(exportPath)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `glob` function in the glob module to get all `.gz` files:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob(r'\\ADC\redshift-datasets\BLSCEWAG2016\**\*.gz', recursive=True)
```

Then, create the data frame and call `df.unique`:

```
gzPath = pd.DataFrame(files, columns=['Path'], dtype=object)['Path'].unique()
```

Save to csv:

```
exportPath = r'D:\Sunil_Work\temp8' + '\\Path.csv'
gzPath.to_csv(exportPath)
```

Comment: @coldspeed, thanks for response. But where I can give Path: adcPath = r'\\ADC\redshift-datasets\BLSCEWAG2016' , I want to fetch from mentioned path not all

Comment: But if subfolder exist, it gives blank, It works only if I give direct folder link that contains .gZ files

Comment: @faithon Okay... Edited my answer. Use the `recursive` flag with `glob`.